# How to introduce yourself as an Exchange Student?

Tags: names, culture

I'd like to know with which name an exchange student will be called (first name or last name), when he/she joins a class at an average Japanese school. On the one hand, it may be the case the "Japanese behavior" is adapted and the student is called by his/her last name, or the student decides themself how to get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of them will call you whatever you want them to call you. Especially since you are a foreigner.

If you were Japanese, they would call you by your family name unless you were very good friends or had a very common name like Sato or Takahashi which was shared with someone else in the class.

Also, unless you got an obvious name like John or Bob, they will probably not be able to tell which one is your family name.

My coworkers almost had a heart attack from the surprise during the last group meeting when they realized they had been calling me by my first name for the past 2 years. They were all sure it was my family name.

Comment: thanks for your answer @stack-reader , and also for the good explanation :)